# edit ps1 file with c#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

i have an ps1 file witch work fine in powerISE.
But in my case ,I have a c# class witch execute ps1 file and I want to set variables values from c# class .

code in PS1 powershell

```
function Add-CompanyContact([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$list,[string]$company, [string]$name)
```

the company and the name are setted by users 
beast regards .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251076/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp

Comment: thank a lot , it works

Comment: Please close Your question or provide answer Yourself, if the problem is solved.

Comment: the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251076/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp it works in my case